# JavaScript Comparison returning same and different

Tags: javascript, php

I am comparing Current Sub and New Sub. It gets the `CurrentSub` from a php file and waits for 4 seconds before getting the `NewSub` from the same file.

When I run this code, it pops up with both the alert for it being the same and the alert for it being different.

I don't understand how it can be the same but different? I'm printing the variables put on screen and they are identical.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var CurrentSub = "<?php echo $Name[1] ; ?>";
    setTimeout(function() {
        var NewSub = "<?php echo $Name[1] ; ?>";
        if (NewSub != CurrentSub) {
            window.alert("different");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.subText').html(NewSub);
            }, 200)

            document.getElementById("Sub1Move").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display = "none";
            $("#Sub1Move").animate({
                marginTop: "-=34px",
            }, 1900, function() {
                document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display = "block";
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#Sub1Move").stop();
                document.getElementById("Sub1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Sub1Move").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Sub1Move").style.marginTop = "34px";

            }, 2000);
            var CurrentSub = "<?php echo $Name[1] ; ?>";
        };
        if (NewSub == CurrentSub) {
            window.alert("same");
        };
    }, 4000);

    $('.test').html(NewSub);
    $('.test1').html(CurrentSub);

}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.subText').html(CurrentSub);
}, 200);
```

Comment: Why do you assign a local variable with the same name as the global (`CurrentSub`) inside your if-statement?

Comment: Also, did you mean to have an `else-if` for the second condition (which could simply be an `else`)?

Comment: As for code-reuse, I see a lot of repeated logic, why not create a function? `function setStyle(id, prop, val) { document.getElementById(id).style[prop] = val; }` Then all you have to do is call: `setStyle('Sub1Move', 'display', 'block');`. Looks a lot nicer and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is executed before:

```
if (NewSub != CurrentSub) {
```

so that the different alert is shown.
Then at the end there is:

```
var CurrentSub = "<?php echo $Name[1] ; ?>";
```

so that now `CurrentSub` and NewSub are equal and so correctly the if statement below evaluates to true:

```
if (NewSub == CurrentSub) {
```

Comment: but it keeps repeating it, i thought my code would show the different alert and then keep showing the same alert over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are creating a race condition. You have new `setTimeout` for 4seconds created at each `setInterval` called. In the end, you have 8 new `setTimeouts` called before the first one is executed. This is a result of each `setInterval` taking 500ms while the nested `setTimeout` takes 4s. Basically, this code smells because you have to keep comparing things when they've already changed. Try not to execute a new `setInterval` before the last one has finished. So, either lengthen the `setInterval` timeout or shorten the nested `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the the variables that get referred to in the closures.
and the hoisting of declarations
your code nests something like this.

```
function scope1(){
    var CurrentSub // local 1
    function scope2()
    {
       var NewSub // local 2
       if(NewSub comparison CurrentSub)//you think you are referring to "local 1" but since you are redeclaring it on this function  you are actually referring to "local 3"
       {
            CurrentSub IS undefined at this point
       }
       var CurrentSub // local 3 .. redeclaration of a var in local scope, is created as undefined in the beginning of the scope, only to be defined at this point
    }
}
```

the simplest solution is to remove `var` from the second `var CurrentSub` to allow the function to refer to the external variable, instead of creating a new for the inner scope.